# Vue: Search by column name

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, datatables

I have the table Where i have a search filter, The search consists of three things `Select column name (e.g "name")`, Select conditional `operator e.g(> or <)`, third `search input e.g(20)`.

So for example it will come `age > 20`.

The following code is not working :

**search_column is select column,

search_operator is condition e.g (> or <),

search_input is to take e.g 20, Altogether age > 20**

```
computed: {
  filteredRow: function() {
    return this.model.data.filter(row => {
      let value = row[this.query.search_column];
      for(var key in row){
        if(String(row[key]).indexOf(this.query.search_input) !== -1){
          switch (this.query.search_operator) {
            case "=": return value == this.query.search_input;
            case ">": return value > this.query.search_input;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The above code is not working because i have to return true in the `if()` in order to populate table first. And for returning true will only work for simple searching from search input.

How can it be done ?

Comment: what is this `for(var...)` statement used for ?

Comment: @Yongfeng the array of objects are coming, Thats why have to use for

Comment: Why do you have the `if` at all?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works fine except you make it too complicated

Let's say you have a table data `this.model.data` :

```
[{
  name: 'Alpha', 
  age: 21
}, {
  name: 'Beta',
  age: 18
}, {
  name: 'Gamma',
  age: 27
}]
```

and when it comes with the conditions:

**search_column is `age`**

**search_operator is condition `>`**

**search_input is `20`**

the below code should return the filtered `Alpha` and `Gamma`

```
computed: {
  filteredRow: function() {
    return this.model.data.filter(row => {
      // filter each row and assert the column `value` 
      let value = row[this.query.search_column] 
      switch (this.query.search_operator) {
        case "=": return value === this.query.search_input;
        case ">": return value > this.query.search_input;
        default: return false; // better to have a default handler
      }
    });
  }
}
```

the `filteredRow` would be:

```
[{
  name: 'Alpha',
  age: 21
}, {
  name: 'Gamma',
  age: 27
}]
```